# LibGit2Sharp: How to push a local repo commit to Azure DevOps remote repo using a Personal Access Token inside a custom HTTP authentication header?

Tags: c#, .net-5, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I am trying to push a commit I made on my local repository to a remote counterpart, hosted on a private Azure DevOps server, using LibGit2Sharp programmatically.

As per the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows#use-a-pat), the HTTPS OAuth enabled Personal Access Token needs to sent with the request in a custom Authentication header as 'Basic' with the Base64 encoded token:

```
var personalaccesstoken = "PATFROMWEB";

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
            Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($":{personalaccesstoken}")));

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(
                    "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.0").Result) {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
```

The [`LibGit2Sharp.CloneOptions` class has a `FetchOptions` field](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/1e6da83ab8c47058b5b4ef1e4e28e4732de44db0/LibGit2Sharp/CloneOptions.cs#L49) which in turn [has a `CustomHeaders` array](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/1e6da83ab8c47058b5b4ef1e4e28e4732de44db0/LibGit2Sharp/FetchOptions.cs#L48) that can be used to inject the authentication header during the clone operation, like the following ([as mentioned in this issue](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1596#issuecomment-977184992)):

```
        CloneOptions cloneOptions = new() {
        CredentialsProvider = (url, usernameFromUrl, types) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials {
            Username = $"{USERNAME}",
            Password = $"{ACCESSTOKEN}"
        },
        FetchOptions = new FetchOptions {
            CustomHeaders = new[] {
                $"Authorization: Basic {encodedToken}"
            }
        }
    };
    Repository.Clone(AzureUrl, LocalDirectory, cloneOptions);
```

And the clone process succeeds (I tested it as well as [checked the source code](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/1e6da83ab8c47058b5b4ef1e4e28e4732de44db0/LibGit2Sharp/Repository.cs#L775) :) )

However, the `LibGit2Sharp.PushOptions` does not have any such mechanism to inject authentication headers. I am limited to the following code:

```
PushOptions pushOptions = new()
        {
            CredentialsProvider = (url, usernameFromUrl, types) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials
            {
                Username = $"{USERNAME}",
                Password = $"{PASSWORD}"
            }
        };
```

This is making my push operation fail with the following message:

> Too many redirects or authentication replays

I checked the source code for [`Repository.Network.Push()` on Github](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/1e6da83ab8c47058b5b4ef1e4e28e4732de44db0/LibGit2Sharp/Network.cs#L374).

```
public virtual void Push(Remote remote, IEnumerable<string> pushRefSpecs, PushOptions pushOptions)
    {
        Ensure.ArgumentNotNull(remote, "remote");
        Ensure.ArgumentNotNull(pushRefSpecs, "pushRefSpecs");

        // Return early if there is nothing to push.
        if (!pushRefSpecs.Any())
        {
            return;
        }

        if (pushOptions == null)
        {
            pushOptions = new PushOptions();
        }

        // Load the remote.
        using (RemoteHandle remoteHandle = Proxy.git_remote_lookup(repository.Handle, remote.Name, true))
        {
            var callbacks = new RemoteCallbacks(pushOptions);
            GitRemoteCallbacks gitCallbacks = callbacks.GenerateCallbacks();

            Proxy.git_remote_push(remoteHandle,
                                  pushRefSpecs,
                                  new GitPushOptions()
                                  {
                                      PackbuilderDegreeOfParallelism = pushOptions.PackbuilderDegreeOfParallelism,
                                      RemoteCallbacks = gitCallbacks,
                                      ProxyOptions = new GitProxyOptions { Version = 1 },
                                  });
        }
    }
```

As we can see above, the `Proxy.git_remote_push` method call inside the `Push()` method is passing a new `GitPushOptions` object, which indeed [seems to have a `CustomHeaders` field implemented.](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/1e6da83ab8c47058b5b4ef1e4e28e4732de44db0/LibGit2Sharp/Core/GitPushOptions.cs#L12) But it is not exposed to a consumer application and is being instantiated in the library code directly!

It is an absolute necessity for me to use the LibGit2Sharp API, and our end-to-end testing needs to be done on Azure DevOps repositories, so this issue is blocking me from progressing further.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to use some other way to authenticate a push operation on Azure from LibGit2Sharp? Can we leverage the `PushOptions.CredentialsProvider` handler so that it is compatible with the auth-n method that Azure insists on?
2. Can we cache the credentials by calling `Commands.Fetch` by injecting the header in a `FetchOptions` object before carrying out the Push command? I tried it but it fails with the same error.
3. To address the issue, is there a modification required on the library to make it compatible with Azure Repos? If yes, then I can step up and contribute if someone could give me pointers on how the binding to the native code is made :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will provide an answer to my own question as we have fixed the problem.

The solution to this is really simple; I just needed to remove the `CredentialsProvider` delegate from the `PushOptions` object, that is:

```
var pushOptions = new PushOptions();
```

instead of,

```
PushOptions pushOptions = new()
        {
            CredentialsProvider = (url, usernameFromUrl, types) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials
            {
                Username = $"{USERNAME}",
                Password = $"{PASSWORD}"
            }
        };
```

¯\*(ツ)*/¯

I don't know why it works, but it does. (Maybe some folks from Azure can clarify it to us.)

Comment: I think this is because it falls back to the DefaultCredentials, which in turn just uses the git settings stored on your PC, probably in credential manager. Of course this is not the solution if you want to work with credentials being passed around.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this works on windows (push options with no credentials provider). Perhaps because somewhere a native call the OS resolves the credentials using some other means. But in Linux / container environment, the issue persists.

"There was a problem pushing the repo: remote authentication required but no callback set"

I think as you mentioned, minimally the CustomHeaders implementation must be exposed for this to work.

[Image of error on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPkTO.png)